How to check the result of a mocked function without relying on calling convention
In Python,
can check the parameters of a mocked function using parameter names in a test without relying on the way the function was called (either with args or with kwargs)?
Concrete example
I'd like this example to return a passing test:

# function under test.
# Please assume that `callback` has proper type annotations.
def domain_code_function(callback):
    callback (1,2,c=3)

# function that would normally be passed to `domain_code_function`
# **Note**: 
#           This function has three params `a`, `b` and `c`.
def add_values(a,b,c):
    return a + b + c

class Tests(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_works(self):
        # setup
        mymock = MagicMock()

        # run
        domain_code_function(mymock)

        # check
        # **Note**:
        #       Verify each parameter by name.
        mymock.assert_called_with(a=1,b=2,c=3)

Constraints:

I don't want to change how the function is called within the domain code (args vs kwargs) (As stated in title as description)

Background
Relying on positional arguments for tests seems brittle and not very well readable.
What I've tried
Using unittest.mock.call:

mymock.assert_has_calls([call(a=1,b=2,c=3)])
By the way, not even checking purely with positional arguments works: mymock.assert_has_calls([call(1,2,3)])

